# dynamically add div to container angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to add a div on click of button, and it should have 1 did added by default and on newly added div i need a class `active` on it

```
 <div class="card-content">
    <div class="questions" *ngFor="let question of questions, let i = index" [ngClass]="{'active': i}">
      <app-question-card></app-question-card>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer" (click)="addNewQuestion()">
    <div class="running-txt">Add new question</div>
  </div>

questions: number[] = [1];
addNewQuestion() {
    this.questions.push(this.questions.length);
  }
```

the add is working as expected but the class is not getting appended the way it should and it is not getiing removed from 1 default added div as well
any idea?

Comment: If you always want class `active` appended, just add it as `class="active"`. Your expression `[ngClass]="{'active': i}` means add class `active` if `i` is truthy (meaning the first item will not have it as `i` is `0` in that case).

Comment: i want to add active only on the last element added in the questions array
by default the question array has one div so active should be on that div and when i click on addNewQuestion() then active should on the lastest added div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply the class `active` to only the last item, you can do it like this;

```
<div class="questions" *ngFor="let question of questions; let last = last" [ngClass]="{'active': last}">
  <app-question-card></app-question-card>
</div>
```

This creates a variable that can be used to identify the last item in the list.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: it will be really helpful if u can help me out on how to pass that active class to the <app-question-card></app-question-card> based on ngClass check as input decorator

Comment: You can use the same expression for you custom component: `<app-question-card [ngClass]="{'active': last}">`. You could also create an @input for your component and set it like `[isLast]="last"`. Good luck :)

Comment: active class can either be on the last element or recently clicked index...
how to manage that?